# Get content of <div> knowing its id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, canvasjs

I am trying to get the content of a  element of which I know partially the id.
The foo variable is correctly generated, but I cannot get it to return a chart object from the div element.
This is the jQuery code I am using:

```
$(".addViewport").click(function () {                   

  var foo = "#" + $(this).parent().children('div[id$="_chart"]').attr('id');

  var chart = foo.CanvasJSChart();

  chart.options.axisX.viewportMaximum += 86400000;
  chart.render();

});
```

And this is the html:

```
<div id="temperature">
    <div id="temperature_chart" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
    <button class="addViewport">Viewport +</button>
</div>
```

The chart library I am using is called CanvasJS and it has a method called [.CanvasJSChart();](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/integration/jquery/) to get the chart from specific div element.[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `foo` contains a string, which probably doesn't have a method named `CanvasJSChart`. Maybe you need `$(foo).CanvasJSChart()`?

Comment: I have just tried it but apparently it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line returns a string (`"#temperature_chart"`):

```
var foo = "#" + $(this).parent().children('div[id$="_chart"]').attr('id');
```

and that's why this line cannot work:

```
var chart = foo.CanvasJSChart();
```

---

`foo` needs to become a jQuery object in order for all that to work. For example:

```
var foo = $(this).parent().children('div[id$="_chart"]');
```

Comment: How do you suggest I should change it?

Comment: The last line of my answer will make `foo` a jQ object.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in JSFiddle:

```
$(".addViewport").parent().children().get(0)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fyvh0o56/